# how to show all VirtueMart Product list

Tags: joomla1.5, virtuemart

i am creating a component in Joomla that shows a list of virtuemart Product

the requirement is that i can not use code directly from sql table.

so i use `components/com_virtuemart/virtuemart_parser.php`

for code i get the list of category in array , and code is

```
require_once( CLASSPATH . 'ps_product_category.php');
$ps_product_category = new ps_product_category();
$tpl = new $GLOBALS['VM_THEMECLASS']();
$category_childs = $ps_product_category->get_child_list(0);
$tpl->set( 'categories', $category_childs );
$categories = ps_product_category::getCategoryTreeArray(true);
```

from this code i get all published category, but how to get all products from category

```
how to show product list, how to get product list in array ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The only existing function products_in_category(), but that doesn't meet your need because it only returns the number of products.

A non-SQL solution is to create a custom VM function and put it in

```
root\components\com_virtuemart\themes\default\theme.php
```

If you clone/modify ps_product::featuredProducts(), you should get what you want quite easily. (also, that file location assumes that you're using the default VM theme, as installed)

Answer (score 0):

To show categories products in another component you can use this:

```
if (!class_exists( 'VmConfig' )) require(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_virtuemart'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'config.php');
VmConfig::loadConfig();
if (!class_exists( 'VmModel' )) require(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_virtuemart'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'vmmodel.php');
$categoryModel = VmModel::getModel('Category');
$cats = $categoryModel->getCategoryTree();//Params $parentId=0, $level = 0, $onlyPublished = true,$keyword = ''
if (!class_exists('VirtueMartModelProduct')) require(JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'models' . DS . 'product.php');
$product_model = new VirtueMartModelProduct();
for ($x = 0; $x < count($cats); $x++) {
    echo $cats[$x]->category_name."<Br/>";
    $products = $product_model->getProductsInCategory($cats[$x]->virtuemart_category_id);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
        echo "- ".$products[$i]->product_name."<Br/>";
    }
}
```